# autocomplete view broken (iscroll issue)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, autocomplete, iscroll4

I need an autocomplete option in my phonegap app, and i got [this sample](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) . It works fine when iam working with sample, but it is broken (look at images) when iam trying to scroll in iphone simulator i think it has some css issue, how can i fix it ? Iam really got stuck with this. Thanks.

> Update1: this issue arises when my iscroll started to scroll. Then, my list also starting to scroll (as i shown in below image).
>
> Update2:
>   my [**jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FPJP7/2/), enter 'a' in products input field - a list will appear, then scroll; you can see the issue.

my scroll wrapper:

```
var testScroll;

function loaded() {
  testScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
  //check js fiddle for more 
 }
}false);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: When does that happen? Is it when you start typing and then scroll the page? What version of iScroll you're using?

Comment: @caiocpricci2: yeah, exactly... iam using iScroll 4.2.5

Comment: still not solved!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use iscroll  only when the  target doesn't support touch-based scrolling of fixed regions. (see more http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/)

If all you need is autocomplete for phone gap, you might eventually find what you are looking for in the tutorial linked above ;)

Comment: thanks.. but it is not the issue.Issue arises- when it came iscroll and autocomplete together...