# How to show list with 'plenty of items' in Phonegap mobile app

Tags: jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, cordova, jquery-autocomplete, iscroll

Iam developing a phonegap  app which has a drop down with 400+ items, as a mobile phone application which is the appropriate way to show such numerous items, i have tried [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) `jquery`, but it has some issues as shown in the below jsfiddle.

*In below JSfiddle, type 'a' in products
 input field, a list will appear, then scroll upwards; you can see the issue.*

my **[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FPJP7/2/)**,
Iam struggling with this for weeks, i need your suggestion. 
thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle, so we can have a look?

Comment: @frequent: jsfiddle is there, check it pls..

Comment: I don't see the problem. If I add "a" in the input you mention, the autocomplete shows the number of remaining items. As a more general issue, you should not mix JQM and JqueryUI until it is safe to do so. So if you want to do JQM only, have a look at these examples [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/filterable/) and [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/listview-autocomplete-remote/) which show how to do a listview filter with local or remote data. This way no need to use jQueryUi and probably no errors either

Comment: issue is there...,u can see the issue if u scroll upwards after typing 'a' in 'products' field..

Comment: sorry. I don't see anything... Can you post a screenshot :-)

Comment: check this link u can see the screenshot captured from simulator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739895/autocomplete-view-broken-iscroll-issue

Comment: @frequent: check above link.

Comment: I saw the link. In this question you are having problems with `iscroll`, on your fiddle you are using `jqueryUI` - you said earlier you solved it with the JQM filterable (change the theme by using the options provided in [filterable](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/filterable/) such as `data-filter-theme` to set the theme of your filter. Regarding jQueryUI and iscroll compatability I can't help. sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41099/discussion-between-mvp-and-frequent)